# How to tap into a corner fuse with a lip/wall on two surrounding sides

Tags: fuse, fuse-panel

I'm trying to tap into this fuse box:

[image]

...using a standard fuse tap, like so:

[image]

The problem is that the fuse slot I want to tap into is right in the corner and there is a wall/lip that runs on two sides of the slot.
The fuse taps I have protrude from three dimensions, where I only have two dimensions of free space, resulting in one of the three protrusions blocking the fuse tap from properly seating into the slot.

Are there any products on the market to alleviate this issue?

Comment: I would either trim the edge of the fuse adaptor or access the wires feeding the fuse.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your first suggestion? As for your second, I'd prefer not to alter any existing wiring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use a different type of fuse tap. If you used one like the one below, you could bend the tang over and run the wire straight down and out of the way. (Note: You're looking at just the brass part here.)

[image]

Comment: If I went for this solution and I needed a lower rated fuse for the added device, would I also put in an inline fuse between the new device and that tap?

Comment: It looks like what you're suggesting is what this person recommends here: https://youtu.be/8b9CvUMcNQo?t=298, but what the are the male and female parts called individually?

Comment: Can you get ones that fit micro2 fuses? I can only find mini/ATM and even then they are hard to find.